# How to get the keycodes from the controller in javascript?

Tags: javascript, controller, keycode, xbox360

I did buy a cheap controller (windows thinks it's a xbox 360 controller) and I want to get some javascript keypress events from the controller. I did try some keycode testers online like http://keycode.info/ but they didn't gave something back. My question is how do i get the keycodes from the controller in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gamepad's key press are not handled by events. It's a Object's property stored in:

```
navigator.getGamepads()[$1].buttons[$2].pressed;
```

**$1** an integer, from 0 to 3, so you can have up to 4 gamepads to control. 
**$2** an integer, from 0 to 16 in my case ;

so, we must check it by ourself.

**navigator.getGamepads()** returns a **Gamepad List**, which looks like this:

```
{0: null, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null, length: 4}
```

if a controller connected, it looks like this:

```
{0: Gamepad, 1: null, 2: null, 3: null, length: 4}
```

the first element is a  **Gamepad** Object, it looks like this:

```
{
    axes: [0, 0, 0, 0], //these are directions keys;
    buttons: [GamepadButton, GamepadButton, ...] //these are buttons;
    connected: true, 
    id: "ACGAM R1", 
    index: 0,
}
```

elements in **buttons** List are **GamepadButton** Objects, it looks like this:

```
{pressed: false, value: 0}
```

if you are using *Google Chome*, you can check all these information by typing `navigator.getGamepads()` in *dev-tools*( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open it ) in *console* .

if you have a gamepad in hand, you can test it use this:

```js
function gameLoop() {
    var gamepad = navigator.getGamepads()[0]; //get the first controller.
    if (gamepad && gamepad.connected) {
        //check if direction buttons (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) was pressed
 var axes = gamepad.axes;
 for (var i in axes) {
     if (axes[i] != 0) { print('axes[%s] value is: %s', i, axes[i]); };
 };
 // to check if other buttons(A,B,C,D,OK,Exit...) was pressed
 var buttons = gamepad.buttons;
 for (var i in buttons) {
     if (buttons[i].pressed == true) { print("buttons[%s] pressed", i); };
 };
    };
};

var game_loop ;

//when controller connected, page will show: "Gamepad connected"
window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", function(e) {
    print("Gamepad %s connected at %d", e.gamepad.id, e.gamepad.index);
    game_loop = setInterval(gameLoop, 50);  //check if a button was pressed 20 times every second.
});

//when controller disconnected, page will show: "Gamepad disconnected"
window.addEventListener("gamepaddisconnected", function(e) {
    print("Gamepad %s disconnected", e.gamepad.id);
    clearInterval(game_loop);  // stop checking

});
//end of the code.

//nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
// not about control keys
function print() {
    var args = ['== no string == ',];
    for (var i in arguments) { args[i] = arguments[i]; };
    var s = args[0], vs = args.slice(1);
    for (var i in vs) { s = s.replace(/%[a-z]/, vs[i]); };
    document.body.innerHTML = s ;
};
```

```html
<html>
<title> test Gamepad buttons</title>
<body>
no Gamepad deteced!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  alert("key: " + event.key + ", code: " + event.code);
}, true);
```

Comment: i just try'd but no respond only the homebutton gave back "key: unidefined code: "

Answer (score 1):

The basic [Events interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) does not have support for gamepads. But there is another API for that:

> > This is an experimental technology
> >     Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production.
>
> **HTML5** introduced many of the necessary components for rich, interactive game development. Technologies like **< canvas >**, **WebGL**, **< audio >**, and **< video >**, along with JavaScript implementations, have matured to the point where they can now support many tasks previously requiring native code. **The Gamepad API** is a way for developers and designers to access and use gamepads and other game controllers.
>
> **The Gamepad API** introduces new events on the Window object for reading gamepad and controller *(hereby referred to as gamepad)* state. In addition to these events, the API also adds a `Gamepad` object, which you can use to query the state of a connected gamepad, and a `navigator.getGamepads()` method which you can use to get a list of gamepads known to the page.

### [Click here to find out more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API)

Answer (score 0):

I did ending up using a tool called JoyToKey.